# LINQ Show every Record from table A exactly once when it exists at least once in Table B

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have to tables, Table A is master, table B child.

What is the simplest LINQ2SQL Query to show all records from Table A exactly once
that have at least a child in table B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
var AsWithBs = db.TableA.Where(x => x.Bs.Any())
```

or

```
var AsWithBs = from a in db.TableA
               where a.Bs.Any()
               select a;
```

Comment: thanks, works great, I think the 

where a.Bs.Any()

is the clearest solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = (from record in database.records where record.children.Any()).Distinct();
```